# Connect one Confluent Control Center to multiple Kafka clusters

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have multiple Kafka instances and only one Confluent Control Center. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean multiple Kafka clusters? Or multiple brokers within one cluster?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt multiple clusters

Comment: Yes. It's possible. What issues are you having? What configurations are you currently using?

Comment: Questions asking "Is there a way to do X?" / "Can I do X?" / "Is it possible to do X?" are rarely appropriate for the Stack Exchange format. The answer is usually "yes", but sometimes "no". Either way, the question is usually not very effective. In addition, what is usually meant is "How can I do X?", which will often, but not always, be too broad for Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to clarify what it is you want. Right now, this is a "yes"/"no" question. Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to add multiple clusters to Confluent Control Center. Beyond the base cluster, bootstrap servers can be configured for other clusters in `etc/confluent-control-center/control-center.properties`.

Replace `<name>` with a unique identifier of another cluster:

- `confluent.controlcenter.kafka.<name>.bootstrap.servers`

For example, if you wanted to add a `docker` cluster hosted at `docker:9092`, you would add:

- `confluent.controlcenter.kafka.docker.bootstrap.servers=docker:9092`